# Send json in a POST from a web view in React Native

Tags: javascript, json, post, react-native

Hi (Sorry for my english)

I have a POST service and I have to send some parameters in json format, but I don't find a solution. I found an example in the page number three of Google haha, but I need to send a object array and I don't know how I can send un array.

```
<WebView
        source={
       {
       uri: Urls.base + '/store/checkout',
       method: 'POST',
       headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       },
       body: "param1=test&param2=test"
}} />
```

In ReactNative Documentation say that "body" param is a String, so I can't send a json.

I should send this json

```
{
    "delivery": 2,
    "payment": 1,
    "userName": "test@test.pe",
    "name": "Joseph",
    "lastname": "Test",
    "userEmail": "tes@test.pe",
    "userPhone": "11223344",
    "userAddress": "Av AAA 742",
    "totalAmount": 1500,
    "user": 5,
    "detail": [
        { "product": 1, "quantity": 2 },
        { "product": 2, "quantity": 1 },
        { "product": 5, "quantity": 3 }
    ]
}
```

thanks

Comment: Just stringily your object with `body: JSON.stringify(data)` where `data` is your object.

Comment: @Striped Thank you. I don't know because I started running in circles when the solution was so easy haha

Comment: I feel you bro.